# How to use PHP to analyze a page and create an HTML file based on criterias?

Tags: php, html, web-crawler

My idea is that I have a certain page in a website I'm developing that calls a search and prints a page with the results.

But because the way this page is presented, my Sitemap program does not crawl it and also Google does not crawl the page correctly so I had the following idea:

- Using PHP, the script would access this page, analyze its contents and copy a certain portion of every search into an static HTML file. In this way, Google could crawl the newly created file with no problems.

The page in question is http://www.fc-corner.com/es/all-listings/

There you will see that a long search is performed and several items appear. I would like to copy everything inside the `<h3></h3>` of each result in the search and add it to an html file for later use by the Sitemap program and search engines. I would then create a Cron Job to periodically update this file.

Is such a thing possible or I'm going too far?

Comment: You can retrieve the HTML of the site with cURL and parse it with XPath. By the way, the site you linked to does not load for me.

Comment: Condensed, is your question "is it possible to create a static sitemap programmatically"? If so, then yes, it is. You can even create a sitemap dynamically if you so choose, either is good. Your page looks like it is created from a database, so it would be easier to create your sitemap from that, rather than analysing the HTML content of your generated PHP page.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply and editing :) the reason for me to think about this method is because the website is multi language and the translation is done using XML language files (the website is based on smarty), so this is not stored in the database, but translated "on-the-fly" if you wish.